# Why u-boot always mark writed block as bad?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, u-boot

I'm developing an nand flash driver of u-boot. I think it works well but the environment of u-boot doesn't work properly. Here is what i have done for testing:

1. Erase the whole nand flash by code purely coded by myself, these codes are not related to u-boot. And no bad blocks found. (Is it possible for a nand flash to have no bad block?). Here is the code

   ```
   void nand_erase(u32 addr)
   {   
       if (addr & (BLOCK_SIZE - 1))
       {
           printf("not block align\n");
           return;
       }
       u32 row = addr / 2048;

       nand_select_chip();
       nand_cmd(0x60);

       NFADDR = row & 0xFF;            
       NFADDR = (row >> 8) & 0xFF;
       NFADDR = (row >> 16) & 0x07;

       nand_cmd(0xD0);
       nand_wait_ready();

       nand_cmd(0x70);
       u8 status = nand_read();
       if (status & 0x01)
       {
           printf("block 0x%x is bad", addr);
       }

       nand_deselect_chip();
   }
   ```
2. Start u-boot, it prompt"bad CRC ,using default environment".
3. Now i use "setenv test 100" and "printenv test", it works well, and "saveenv", it prompt "OK" as well.
4. And i use "nand bad", it shows nothing.
5. Restart the board and u-boot
6. Now it says that "readenv() failed, using default environment".
7. And i "printenv test", it fails. Then i chekced "nand bad", it shows a bad block exactly at "CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET"
8. Then i changed CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET to another value. and repeat step 1-7. It will shows a bad block again at the new CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET.

I've checked my driver, the write operation and read operation are good i think. The steps are here:

1. "nand dump 0" , and it shows all 0xff
2. "nand write 20000000 0 800" to write memory into nand flash.
3. Then "nand dump 0", it shows the same values as "md 20000000 100" does.

So, you can see that after saveenv, the block at CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET will be marked as bad, I really don't know why

Comment: Have you tried `nand write` and `nand dump` to write and read the block where the environment is stored? Maybe that block is bad and your erase code isn't recognizing it.

Comment: You need to get details on why the **readenv()** fails.  That could provide a clue as to why the write then read is not correct.  Perhaps ECC is not generated correctly. BTW in general erasing *"the whole nand flash"* is a bad idea, as you lose any factory-marked bad blocks.

Comment: @DoxyLover: Actually, the environment stays at the address specified by "CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET", And as my post, i have changed it multiple times, and the situation stand still.

Comment: @sawdust I've already checked, sorry i forgot to write it. It returns at {if(nand_block_isbad())} called by {readenv()},which exactly means that u-boot marked it as bad block

Comment: First, you should follow u-boot's driver models. It makes things more easier. When you "write" the data, what do you write to the OOB (out of band) area? u-boot uses the OOB area for many things (including as a bad block marker). Read the original u-boot NAND driver code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i figure out.
I set ecc.mode = NAND_ECC_HW_SYNDROME, But XXX_syndrome function doesn't maintain ecc layout. It just simply write ecc after main data. Finally it will override the first and second bytes of oob area in each page , but u-boot check these two bytes as bad block marker, so here is the answer.